# Creating an array and extracting only some data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Not sure if I titled this correctly. I've been stuck on this problem for a while.

[image]

Table on the left is my data.

Table on the right is my generated data from formulas. (except H)

I want G to show something similar to what H shows.

The logic I want to implement:

**If F is greater than 0, then show the projects that are late in a condensed form**

I thought about just manually saying if "project 1 - extra stuff I don't want" "project 1".

Even a solution like that would work since we only have 8 projects, but I'm not sure how to even do that.

Comment: Unless you have specific rules for a "condensed form", this can't be implemented (easily, anyway). In other words, if there is **always** an underscore (or some other specific character) between the project name and the "extra stuff", it can be done, but how can Excel know what is the condensed form is if you don't follow a specific rule to indicate what the condensed form is?

Comment: Come to think of it, probably an even better solution would be to just have an extra column for your data and call it a "comment" column. So for example instead of having the text "Phase 1 - Extra Stuff" all in one cell, just split it up so that "Phase 1" is under the "Project Name" column and "Extra Stuff" is under the newly added "comment" column.